# Merging two formvars in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the columns `voornaam` en `familienaam` together in the column `volledige_naam`.
But I also want to keep the fields `voornaam` en `familienaam` in my database.

I've tried to work around with the `if` function but I'm keep getting errors.

Anyone an idea how I need to go about this?

mysql table creator script.

```
function CreateTable()
{
    $qry = "Create Table $this->tablename (".
        "id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,".
        "volledige_naam VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "voornaam VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "familienaam VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "adres VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "postcode VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "gemeente VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "dob VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "tele VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,".
        "confirmcode VARCHAR(32) ,".
        "PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )".
        ")";

    if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Collection of input script

```
function CollectRegistrationSubmission(&$formvars)
    {
        $formvars['voornaam'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['voornaam']);
        $formvars['familienaam'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['familienaam']);
```

Insert into mysql script.

```
function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
{

    $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

    $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

    $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            volledige_naam,
            voornaam,
            familienaam,
            adres,
            postcode,
            gemeente,
            dob,
            tele,
            email,
            username,
            password,
            confirmcode
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['volledige_naam']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['voornaam']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['familienaam']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['adres']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['postcode']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['gemeente']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['dob']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['tele']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
            "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
            "' . $confirmcode . '"
            )';
    if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: You need to stop using those `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated for 6 years now. PDO has been around for more than a decade.

Comment: Storing duplicated data in the database isn't ideal. Why don't you keep them separated and join when using, with PHP? You can also get them already joined from your select query. Is that what you want?

Comment: I need to data duplicated for search reasons. I just can't figure out how I get them together.

Comment: even for search reasons, you could let them separate in the database. MySQL handles pretty well searching by combining different fields searches

Comment: "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['voornaam'])  $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['familienaam']) . '"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your records in two  columns and join them easily in PHP or
in your  query later. But  if you want to  store them in  another column
anyway, you  can join then at  your insert query. Just  change one line,
instead of passing the  `$formvars['volledige_naam'])` which is probably
nonexistent in your form, pass the joined vars:

```
$formvars['voornaam'] . ' ' . $formvars['familienaam']
```

If you  opt by storing them  separated only, in your  `SELECT` query you
can use something like the following  to retrieve both names in a single
column:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', voornaam, familienaam) AS volledige_naam FROM gebruikers
```

Or  you can  retrieve them  separately  and join  them with  PHP with  a
similar approach.  Also, as noted in  the comments, you should  be using
[PHP DataObjects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php),  PDO for  short. The  old `mysql_`  functions were
deprecated long time ago.